# CakePHP and scaffold views

Tags: cakephp, view, scaffold

Where can I edit scaffold views?
In Cake Book is information about:

`Custom scaffolding views for a specific controller 
(PostsController in this example) should be placed like so:`

/app/views/posts/scaffold.index.ctp
/app/views/posts/scaffold.show.ctp
/app/views/posts/scaffold.edit.ctp
/app/views/posts/scaffold.new.ctp

Custom scaffolding views for all controllers should be placed like so:

/app/views/scaffolds/index.ctp
/app/views/scaffolds/show.ctp
/app/views/scaffolds/edit.ctp
/app/views/scaffolds/new.ctp
/app/views/scaffolds/add.ctp

But it's not work for my application. So, how to edit scaffold views?

Comment: Is there an error or does it just not take effect?

Comment: maybe it's caching... try clearing it.

Comment: Okay all is ok now, I found the solution.

Comment: What was the solution?  You should post it down below if you still remember.